# Remove Stopwords in French AND English

Tags: python, nltk, stop-words

I am trying to remove stopwords in french and english. So far, I've only managed to remove stopwords from one language at a time. I have a text document containing 700 lines of text mixed in french and english.

I am doing a clustering project of these 700 lines using Python. However, the problem arises with my clusters. I am getting a cluster full of french stopwords and this is messing up the efficiency of my cluster.

**Here's my stopwords code:**

```
stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
```

As mentionned, I am trying to include 'french' stopwords in there as well, but unable to do so in one line of code or in the same variable.

**Here's the code including my file containing my 700 lines of mixed french and english descriptions:**

```
Description2 = df['Description'].str.lower().apply(lambda x: ' 
'.join([word for word in str(x).split() if word not in (stopwords)]))
```

I have tried to add 2 stopwords variables inside the line of code above, but it only removes the stopwords of the 1st variable.

**Here's an example of a cluster that I get due to french stopwords not being removed:**

```
Cluster 5:
 la
 et
 dans
 les
 des
 est
 du
 le
 une
 en
```

If I am able to remove french stopwords from my document, I will be able to have clusters that are representative of the actual words that are recurring in my document.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try to simply add the french stopwords to the english stopwords ? This way for example (and use I will use [set()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) for efficiency as mentioned in the [nltk tutorial](https://pythonspot.com/nltk-stop-words/)) :

```
stopwords = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')) | set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('french'))
# This way, you've got the english and french stop words in the stopwords variable

Description2 = df['Description'].str.lower().apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in str(x).split() if word not in stopwords]))
```

Comment: @OnThaRise happy to have helped you :D . 
Do not hesitate to accept the answer to your questions when they are solved, it will help other people when they'll face to the same problem and it will mark your gratitude :) (a good comment is nice for the one who answer the question, an accepted answer is better for the whole usability of the site)

Comment: Perfect! I did not know that! Just checked it and will do so in the future!

Comment: I tried to add the same stopword code to my stopwords in my tf-idf code.. however, it's not working. Is there a way to add french and english stopwords to my tf-idf code? I wrote stop_words = 'english' but I'm unable to add french as well. It says that french stopwords are not built in tf-idf.

Comment: @OnThaRise If you have another question, please ask a new question, comments are not designed for this :) (and without code and/or more context, it will be difficult to help you :) )

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
import nltk
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce


df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Description': ['hello', 'dupa']})

def apply_filtering(val, df):
    df['Description'] = df['Description'].str.lower()
    df['Description'] = df['Description'].apply(lambda x: str(x).split())
    df['Description'] = (df['Description']
                         .apply(lambda x: [word for word in x if word not in (nltk.corpus.stopwords.words(val))])
                         )
    df['Description'] = df['Description'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x))
    return df


elo = lambda l: reduce(lambda y,x: apply_filtering(x,y), l, df)
elo(['english', 'french'])
```